# What are these small white bugs all over my house and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: pest-control, insect, house

What are the small white bugs that are often found on black surfaces in my house? They are very smaller than ants. They seem to be all over the items in the house (Not only on black surfaces but others as well), including chairs, electric items, bottles, cooking items, etc. I have been in a few rental houses over the past few years, and it's like they are following me wherever I go. I am wondering what they are and how to get rid of them. Any advice would be appreciated.

[Video Here](https://i.imgur.com/rkplbF1.mp4)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry but this is not a DIY question. Perhaps you'll have better luck elsewhere.

Comment: @P2000 But I see there are questions related to the insects. And the tags like `insect` and `pest-control` are here.

Comment: The Biology Stack?

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the suggestion. I will post there.

Comment: Those are not bugs. Those are Styrofoam from packaging.

Comment: Did you check the video? They are moving. They are very tiny. Until you closely look into them they are not noticeable.

Comment: Nowhere near enough detail to answer, in any case.

Comment: Closed for lack of detail on Biology as well: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/112047/38451

Comment: Try taking a more closeup photo

Comment: Do you have plants? Did you have a close look them? Small aphids look a lot like that, but they usually don't run around the house (that I know).

Comment: Mold Mites possibly?